# JRebel works ! but does not change the JAR file

Tags: java, jrebel

Hi I am trying the JRebel. It's awesome for me.
I got a problem when I'm trying JRebel remote server function.

[this is very easy simple code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfzpd.png)

[just print count with prefix eeee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P3lI.png)

[change the prefix eeee -> ffff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Jx8.png)

[JRebel catch the change and apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdwSY.png)

[but it back to eeee when i start application again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QauWl.png)

It seems JRebel didn't really change the JAR file. How can I fix the problem?

Thanks for your reading and help.

Comment: If you believe that it should change the JAR file, try contacting them directly via https://www.jrebel.com/contact-us. JRebel has very good support and they should reply shortly

Answer (score 1):

I got response from JRebel Support Team.JRebel has very good support just like mckszcz said.

That is the relay

> The real JAR file isn't changed, because JRebel doesn't change the contents of the JAR file that is in your remote server. We monitor the changes that you have made in the target folder that is in IntelliJ, so to save your changes permanently, you have to rebuild your project before you close it to overwrite the contents of the real JAR file.